# Starting Resources for the New Pathfinder Player

Tags: pathfinder-1e, new-players, system-introduction

I've been invited to play in a friend's Pathfinder game.

I have very, very limited tabletop experience. I really don't want to go in cold (these are experienced players), so while it would be easy for me to grab a Beginner's box, I would like to play a solo adventure to get acclimated to the system.

Most of the resources I've come across so far are single player, but single player in the sense that they are 1 GM and 1 player. I'm not going to find anyone else to play with between now and the game.

The DnD Red Box has a solo adventure in it, and I've come across Dark Awakenings, but these use 4e.

What single player (truly single player) resources would you recommend that I use/play/practice with to get acclimated to Pathfinder's rules and mechanics so that the GM and other players don't spend half the night explaining to me core, fundamental concepts?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello. If you have time I could help you learn the basics of the system. Join us in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) and we can discuss it.

Comment: Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/22625/how-do-i-learn-to-become-a-good-gm/22626#22626 (About becoming a GM but a lot of it points at actual play resources), and http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49781/how-to-play-a-published-adventure-solo (running a published adventure solo). There's not pure solo for Pathfinder otherwise (see [tag:solo] and [tag:one-on-one]).

Comment: Be aware. The game is very complex and every group has some variation on how they apply the rules. Even if you find some way to play it before they teach you, it's easy to misunderstand some rules or learn rules they huseruled.

Comment: @Aaron I wish I had the time to join you yesterday. Thank you for the offer. I can handle house rules, but I'd love to have at least a basic understanding before I jump in.

Comment: @DeveloperDad I am still available if you have any questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pathfinder isn't designed for solo games sadly, and a google hasn't found anything helpful.

What I'd recommend instead is to

- Browse the numerous examples and intros on *youtube*; there are explanations about how to build characters, sample games being played (recommended, watching a game get played is a great way of seeing how a game works)
- Talk to the other players; if they've played before ask them for advice and/or the GM - see if there's something that can be done to help you learn about it.
- I'd also recommend pick one of the simpler (ie non-magical) classes to get you going, without spells to look up your gaming experience will be easier to get into.
- Once you've done this you can simulate a simple fight yourself; get a monster (say an Orc) vs a sample warrior character; roll for initiatives, do some fighting and see how that works. Most of Pathfinders mechanics focus on beating stuff up so if you can learn that then you're pretty solid.
- Ask the GM for a quick intro; see if they can spare an hour or two for you on your own to go through stuff and run a sample combat, character generations etc.

Answer (score 2):

Paizo have basically all the core rules online at http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ and D20 PFSRD have an equally useful site: [www.d20pfsrd.com/](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/).

These sites were invaluable to me when I started playing for the first time, but really the best way to learn is through playing. You could maybe set yourself a little encounter and try to take yourself through it as both GM and a player. Your GM probably won't object to talking you through skill-checks and stuff on the day.

When it comes to creating a character, try out the [PC Gen software](http://pcgen.sourceforge.net/01_overview.php), which really helps me with character creation and leveling.

Good luck!